# Excel VBA: Importing/browsing files in folder

Tags: vba, excel

I have a concerned regarding importing/browsing files using VBA. It is working as expected, I can import or select files from the folder. However, there is a dialog box popped out every time I processed the selected file (see image below). Is it possible to remove this dialog box? Or is it because the file is too large to handle?
[image]

Here is my code for selecting the file from the folder:

```
Dim FSO As Object
Dim FD As Object

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

'select/browse file in folder path
If FD.Show = -1 Then
    Filename = FD.SelectedItems(1)
    Filename = FSO.getfile(Filename)
End If

txtBoxOld.Text = Filename
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try adding Application.DisplayAlerts = False in the beginning of your code.

Comment: I doubt that dialog is being generated from the file selection - Excel typically displays that when you close a workbook after, well, putting a large amount of information on the Clipboard. What are you doing with the selected file to "process" it?

Comment: I need to copy the data from the 2 different selected files and compare the difference between the files.

Comment: @Imran Malek - Thank you. It is working now. :)

Comment: @YoonaMay You're welcome.

Comment: Don't forget to add Application.DisplayAlerts = True at the end of the code.

Comment: Hi @5202456 - May I know what's the difference between adding Application.DisplayAlerts = False in the beginning and adding Application.DisplayAlerts = True at the end?

Comment: Once you set it to False , excel will not display any alert until you set it to True again.

Answer (score 4):

Setting `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` is a bit like just sticking your fingers in your ears and saying I CAN'T HEAR YOU. The problem is that it will mute *every* alert, not just the one you're concerned about.

If you want to purge the clipboard before the end of the subroutine, use `Application.CutCopyMode=False` and you won't get the error.